# Is that normal that when running collectstatic with django, python modules are also copied ?

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I would like to host a Django application on an Apache server using mod_wsgi.

Up to now I have been in dev environment using the runserver utility of Django.

I am surprised that when I run collecstatic command from Django python modules files are also copied in the STATIC_ROOT. I would expect to have only css, and image files...

Is that the normal behavior ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

collectstatic simply copies all the files it finds in the directories you specified for it to look at. Which exactly these are depends on what finders you use (`STATICFILES_FINDERS` in the settings.py). By default the `AppDirectoriesFinder` is enabled, which looks at directories named 'static' within your app directories, as well as `FileSystemFinder`, which looks in the directories specified under `STATICFILES_DIRS` in your settings.py.

All files within these directories will be copied. Django doesn't differentiate between Python files (e.g. models, views...) and other file types. So I guess you must have your Python files in the wrong directory or the wrong directory on the lookup path. You should check your directory structure to solve your problem. You may, however, quick-fix it by using `./manage.py collectstatic -i *.py` which, according to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic), makes collectstatic ignore all files with .py extension. Haven't tested that, though.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found it was because I accidentally forgot a trailing comma in the `STATICFILES_DIRS` tuple.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('', os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'static')), # trailing comma to make this a tuple
)
```

As is the case with Python, without at least one comma in round brackets, it is interpreted as a function call which confused the the setting.

Generally, it's always good practice in Django settings to put a trailing comma on every list and tuple item, or use lists exclusively as they don't need commas for single items.